# RxJava performing operation on a list and returning an observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm new to RxJava (specifically, RxJava2) and I'm having some trouble with what seems to be a relatively easy operation. I need to get some data from a db, iterate through the data (it is represented as a list), perform an operation on each item, wrap the data in another object and return. This is what I have so far:

```
mDataManager
    .getStuffList(id)
    .flatMapIterable(listOfStuff -> listOfStuff)
    .flatMap(item ->
         mDataManager
             .performCount(id, item.getTitle())
             .doOnNext(item::setCounter)
             .takeLast(1)
             .map(counter -> item))
    .toList()
    .toObservable()
    .flatMap(listOfStuff -> Observable.just(new StuffWrapper(listOfStuff));
```

The problem I'm having is that my data manager calls never complete. The idea was that whenever the underlying data changes, the UI changes as well. However, without completing those calls, toList() won't emit the event.

Answer (score 1):

In RxJava 2, `toList` returns a `Single`: it's equivalent to an `Observable` with exactly one item. You can convert it to an Observable by adding `.toObservable`, but that isn't needed that often.

Regarding your other changes, what do you mean by `whenever the underlying data changes`? Does your data manager notify you on data changes?

Edit: if your `mDataManager.getStuffList(id)` call returns an `Observable` that emits multiple items (that is, it never completes but always emits the latest data set after a change), then you need to do something like this:

```
mDataManager
.getStuffList(id)
.flatMap(listOfStuff ->
    Observable
    .from(listOfStuff)
    .flatMap(item ->
         mDataManager
             .performCount(id, item.getTitle())
             .doOnNext(item::setCounter)
             .takeLast(1)
         .map(counter -> item)
         .toList()
    )
)
...
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using `SqlBrite` which is an Rx wrapper around the Android SQLite helper class and it provides notifications for when the data changes. But if I understand my own code correctly, toList() will prevent me from receiving those notifications after the first one? Or am I missing something? And yes I'm using RxJava2

Comment: Well, if you need to call `mDataManager.getStuffList` multiple times (once for each time that your data changes), then you need to wrap everything around that. If OTOH the `getStuffList` call returns a full set of items whenever the stuff changes in the database, then you should skip the `flatMapIterable` and nest everything in that flatMap.

Comment: can you provide an example of the latter? I'm not exactly sure what you mean

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having problems with this - it doesn't seem to compile. First of all, I presume you meant `Observable.fromIterable()` as there's no `from` method on that object? Also where should I use `toList()` operator? As I understand the idea you're suggesting is to return the observable from the database, and on each item perform an action through flatMap. But I'm getting stuck after `doOnNext`